# trying to connect to Active Directory with activeldp and getting a nameerror

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-directory

I am using adauth for authentication. That part is working well.

When a user logs in under adauth, my user table gets populated with the corresponding entries in active directory. However, there can be a situation where a manager needs to create an entry before the employee has initially logged in to the application. I want to be able to query Active Directory

Gemfile

```
gem 'adauth'                        # for active directory/rails integration
gem 'activeldap'                    # required with adauth to provide the
```

I am just trying to establish an activeldap connection in the index method of my observations controller

```
  def index
    @observations = Observation.all
    ActiveLdap::Base.setup_connection(host: 'PDC', port: 389,)
   end
```

PDC is our primary domain controller and I have verified that port 389 is open. I also tried '10.0.0.23' instead of 'PDC'

The error I am getting is

```
NameError in ObservationsController#index
uninitialized constant ObservationsController::ActiveLdap

Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/employee_observations

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/observations_controller.rb:12:in `index'
Request

Parameters:

None
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick note, I guess that's just a typo, but still, you have an extra comma after `389`.

Try forcing Ruby to look for your `ActiveLdap` class from the root namespace by adding `::` before the class name:

```
::ActiveLdap::Base.setup_connection(host: 'PDC', port: 389)
```

Comment: I did fix the comma and also tried the :: .   Neither is getting a connection. I switched over to net/ldap but I'm having issues with that which I'll post in another question.